# Weird root redirection happening on internal URL for Drupal (views/ajax 404 error)

Tags: views, ajax

My site is located at `http://www.example.com/mysite`

For my views on my site, there's one very weird thing happening. Whenever I open a page with a view and use the filters, I get views/ajax 404 error.

This happens because the view wants to go `http://www.example.com/mysite/views/ajax`

instead it is going to 
`http://www.example.com/views/ajax`

Notice `/mysite/` is being missed.

Any idea what's happening?

Comment: Did you add the base path and subdirectory in the settings.php file?

Comment: unfortunately, yes.

Comment: Then it might be the basedir in the .htaccess file? It should include the subfolder as well in some cases.